# QString("%1").arg(number + 1) вывод числа number в формате %03d

Tags: qt

Как с помощью QString можно вывести число в формате %03d ?

Comment: `QString().sprintf("%03d", number + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У [`QString::arg()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-5) есть несколько необязательных параметров. Аналог `%03d` с помощью этого интерфейса будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
QString("%1").arg(number + 1,  /*fieldWidth*/ 3, /*base*/ 10, /*fillChar*/ '0')
```